# How exactly do I do this SQL join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view which is holding data in one table and a table which is holding data in another.

The view has this code

```
SELECT  Underwriter, 
        LTRIM(Agent) AS Agent, 
        DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DateCreated), 0) AS DateCreated, 
        SUM([Unique]) AS Claims 
FROM [C3 ODS].MagentaClaims_Daily_Prefix_VIEW
WHERE (LEFT(Claim_Number, 1) <> 'Z') AND (Claims = 'Y')
GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DateCreated), 0), Agent, Underwriter, DateCreated
ORDER BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, DateCreated), 0)
```

While table has these four columns - `Insurer`, `Agent`, `Day` and `Budgeted Forecast`.

I need to make a join so it produces a final table that joins Underwriter to Insurer, Agent to Agent and DateCreated to Day, with then a figure for claims and then a final column of budgeted amount.

How exactly would I do the join?

There are 39290 records in the view and 10,000 records in the table

I have tried an outer join like this:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
        c3.Underwriter, 
        LTRIM(c3.Agent) AS Agent, 
        DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m, 0, c3.DateCreated), 0) AS DateCreated, 
        SUM(c3.[Unique]) AS Claims, 
        c3_f.Budgeted_Amount
FROM [C3 ODS].MagentaClaims_Daily_Prefix_VIEW c3
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [C3 Forecast].Budget_Data_Dan  c3_f
    ON c3.Underwriter = c3_f.Insurer_Underwriter AND 
        c3.Agent = c3_f.Agent AND 
        c3.DateCreated = c3_f.Day
WHERE (LEFT(c3.Claim_Number, 1) <> 'Z') AND 
        (c3.Claims = 'Y')
GROUP BY DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, c3.DateCreated), 0), 
        c3.Agent, 
        c3.Underwriter, 
        c3.DateCreated, 
        c3_f.Budgeted_Amount
ORDER BY DateCreated
```

But it has only returned 161 records where Ideally I need 10,000 records that will have underwriter, agent, DateCreated, claims and budgeted_amount

The 39121 records in the view have many duplicates so the grouping will then give just the 10,000 records which will have two competitive values - the claims column and the budgeted_Amount

Here is a sample

```
Insurer1 - Agent1   1/6/2016    15  12,
Insurer2 - Agent2   1/6/2016    17  26
```

So the layout is correct but the join isn't returning enough values

Any pointers would be most helpful.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: (1) Tag the question with the database you are using (presumably SQL Server).  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Fixed your query.Please, use table [aliases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: are `date_created` and `day` both dates? Or are they datetimes?

Comment: Hi Matt

date_created - is a Datetime,

day is a Date format

Comment: have you tried casting your DateCreated field to a date type? `convert(datetime, c3.DateCreated`. I often find that joining on datetime can produce wonky results, if not done on for a good reason.

Comment: I didn't build the view only the table so not sure how I can amend the DateCreated field.

Thanks

Comment: Other thing I'm noticing is that you may be misusing your `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, which should return nulls on the left side of the join for claims not in both tables. An inner join would return only rows with both budget and claims. As it stands now, the length of your results are dependent on the length of the right side of the query.

Comment: @DanTracey the convert function I show above just formats it for the given query. You can include it in your join. `convert(DateTime, c3.DateCreated) = c3_f.Day`

Comment: @DanTracey sorry, typo in my last comment. it would be `convert(Date, c3.DateCreated` = c3_f.Day`

Comment: Thanks for all your help - turns out I got given the wrong view to work with, was always going to be an impossible task!